# Check if value exist in db react.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using `class-validator` and I want to check if input exist in PostgreSQL table. If exist, return error else record in table.

It's possible to do that with  `@IsIn()`

```
export class User  {
    
    @IsDefined()
    @ValidateNested()
    @IsIn([value])
    userID?: Identifier;

    constructor(userID: Identifier) {
        super();
        this.userID= userID;
    }
}
```